# intellij 10.5 installation, stuck at "Loading Modules"

Tags: intellij-idea

I successfully installed (no issues reported) intellij 10.5.

However, when I run idea, the app is stuck at a "Loading modules" window...

any ideas...? (pardon the pun...)

Comment: I think the phrase "There is no valid license" refers to StackTrace license and not to IntelliJ IDEA.
Anyway, I got the same behaviour (stuck at "loading modules") from time to time (build #IU-107.105)

Comment: original post updated to remove the unrelated "valid licence" message :-) thanks Marek

Comment: I faced the same issue. IDE stuck at "Loading modules" window. I had changed the VM options which was causing this issue. You can check the error by running intellij from terminal.
I had to remove the flag `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` from `idea.vmoptions` file to make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug.

Try turning off "Tip of the Day" and "Show productivity hints". They are both under the Help menu.

It's been reported a few times.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-67401

Also see issues:
WI-6327,
WI-5994

Comment: I had to quickly hit esc to cancel the project load dialog at startup. Then I was able to load the project manually, then turn off the tip of the day/productivity hints.

Answer (score 3):

Only solution that is working for me is **Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Comment: Same here, this should be the accepted answer. This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

*Adding @Jeremy Brooks comment as an answer here as that worked for me as well:*

Had to quickly hit esc to cancel the project load dialog at startup. (*I repeatedly pressed esc here, and I landed on the open project dialogue*). Then I was able to load the project manually, then turn off the tip of the day/productivity hints.